# Java Apache Derby: Efficient way to append / concatenate String to a big CLOB

Tags: java, out-of-memory, concatenation, derby, clob

The following SQL-code works for me. It concatenates a one line String to a big CLOB in the database:

```
UPDATE tableName SET clobEntry = clobEntry || ? WHERE id = ?
```

But when the CLOB-data grows in size (approx. 30MB), performance decreases dramatically and when the CLOB-size reaches a certain limit an out of memory exception will occur:

> The exception 'java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space' was thrown while evaluating an expression

Is there a possibility to increase performance and improve memory usage?
To improve memory I already release unused Objects by setting them to null so they can be handled by the JVM garbage collector. 
I already used Memory Analyzer and tried to find memory leaks. But the issue comes down to this CLOB concatenation thing. Maybe there is an efficient derby SQL - built in function to use? Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: I forgot to say: I use a PreparedStatement to call the SQL command:  PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sqlUpdateStatement);
     ps.setString(1,stringBuilder.toString());
     ps.setInt(2,id);ps.execute();....

Comment: This kind of feels like a database design issue. It seems to me like each `clobEntry` is a separate piece of data, and so maybe your design should have each entry as a separate clob value in a separate row of another table, joined together with a primary key. That way, adding another entry becomes an `INSERT`, not an `UPDATE`.

Comment: Thank you for the reasonable advice. this would be a good solution for the insert performance of a new CLOB entry. But how would I concatenate the now separate CLOB-Strings together again. Then in each row there would be a one line CLOB that needs to be concatenated together again.

Comment: I could do it easily on the java side. But naively then there would be a thousands of `SELECT` Statements to perform this. This woul take hours to complete?

Comment: I'm not sure how much raw data we're talking about. A single `SELECT` can fetch multiple rows, which are all referenced by the same key in the `WHERE` clause. I don't see a reason that should take any more time to execute than fetching a single row which contains the same amount of data, but as a single giant CLOB value.

Comment: Yes, iteration through the ResultSet on the java side. Yes it would only be one `SELECT` Statement! I will try this solution. Thank you very much!